# How make a floating button in tab navigation bottom?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how to add floating action button inside tab navigation button ?

like the example in the screenshot, I want to add such a button. I've tried adding the floating action button command but instead the button is entered in the profile tab.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: check this link:  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

Comment: im get error in floating actionbutton 'The named parameter 'floatingActionButton' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'floatingActionButton'.dart'

Comment: oh ok" thanks successfull @TDNguyen

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example for your problem:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatelessWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Floating Action Button'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **FloatingActionButton** in the body **tag**

**FloatingActionButton** has the separate tag under *scaffold* like this

```
return Scaffold(
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      // Add your onPressed code here!
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
);
```